# can not import matplotlib or from matplotlib import pyplot as plt as it shows invalid syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

i can not import matplotlib in jupyter notebook
here are the codes which shows syntax errors

1. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
2. `import matplotlib`
3. `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\suhas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-4-99ba79ecbbfb>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

  File "C:\Users\suhas\matplotlib.py", line 13
    ------------------------
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have a file called `matplotlib.py` thats causing some sort of clash. Move it somewhere else if possible, restart the notebook and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a file called `matplotlib.py` in the same folder as where your script is located. Thats where it is importing from (see the error for the destination)